# How do I check and wait for a reaction under a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an event where an embed gets multiple reactions. Here the user has x-seconds to select a reaction. If this is "wrong" an error should be spit out. If the reaction is the desired one, defined by me, another message should appear. I have this code, but I can't get any further:

```py
        await embedX.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await embedX.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await embedX.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        try:
            reaction = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10)
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                await ctx.send("Congrats, right answer.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Incorrect reaction.")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Took too long.")
```

Error:

```py
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'emoji'.
```

I'm still realtively new to Python, so I hope to find help here.

***After I got help my code now looks like the following:***

```py
        e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e.title = "Woah, look!"
        e.description = "**Does this work?**"
        e.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="Yes", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="No", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="Maybe", inline=False)
        e.set_footer(text="You have 10 seconds to answer the question", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        embedX = await ctx.send(embed=e)
        await embedX.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await embedX.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await embedX.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        try:
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10)
            if user == self.bot.user:
                return
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                await embedX.edit(embed=er)
            else:
                await ctx.send(embed=ew)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await embedX.edit(embed=etl)
```

Sometimes the bot counts the reaction, just `1` - to the others he does not react,  but what he is not doing is: Giving out/Editing the embed if the reaction is wrong.
(`er` and `ew` are actually other embeds I defined before.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message should give you a hint: you're receiving a `tuple` from `self.bot.wait_for` and not a `discord.Reaction`.

When using [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), keep in mind what it returns (emphasis mine):

> Returns no arguments, a single argument, or **a tuple of multiple arguments** that mirrors the parameters passed in the event reference.

Looking at the [`on_reaction_add` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), we can see that this event's payload is a `discord.Reaction` and a `discord.User` object. When using `wait_for(<event>)`, you get the same payload as if you were to extend `on_<event>` and handle it that way.

So putting it all together, this line:

```
await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10)
```

Returns a `tuple` with a `Reaction` and a `User`, e.g. `(<Reaction ...>, <User ...>)`. So you just need to make a slight modification:

```
reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10)
```

Here we use tuple unpacking (or multiple assignment, if you prefer) to extract the desired values from the returned tuple.

#### Avoiding Feedback Loops

Since you'll receive *all* events, including those caused by your bot, you'll need to make sure that you ignore the event when it's caused by your bot to avoid a feedback loop. You can trivially guard against this in your event handlers with the following:

```py
# Assuming `self` is an instance of `discord.Client`
if user == self.user:  # `user` here comes from the event payload
    return
```

As a concrete example for your situation:

```py
reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10)
if user == self.bot.user:
    return
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation. However my bot goes crazy because I have not build in a check. Is there something for reactions so that the bot does not count its own reactions as an answer? I guess that is also the reason for my not working `asyncio.TimeoutError`

Comment: In most cases, you'll generally want to ignore events caused by your bot so that you don't end up with feedback loops. You can guard against this pretty easily by checking if the event was caused by your bot: `if user == self.user: return`. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: That is kind of you, thanks. I would have otherwise done it with a payload event but I guess it can be done quicker and easier.

Comment: Either approach is fine, and `wait_for` is a perfectly valid choice here. The *way* you approach them is just slightly different, is all. :)

Comment: Quick question again as I saw your edit: I did it like you did but for `self.user` it says: `Unresolved attribute reference 'user' for class 'Reactions'` - Would I have to put that into my `def __init__`-"event"?

Comment: That was my mistake; I forgot that `self` in your code wasn't a `Client` object. Edited again; it should have read `self.bot.user`.

Comment: Thanks, just found that out too. Is the `return` thing messing with the rest of the code? Somehow it sometimes works, somtimes not - Just reaction 1 gives output. The `else` thing in my code does not work. Let me update my code here for you.

Comment: I'm going to move this to chat, as it's getting a bit lengthy: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227509/chat-for-question-how-do-i-check-and-wait-for-a-reaction-under-a-message-6578